# How to update only selected records in Django queryset like in admin panel actions?

Tags: python, django

Immediately I apologize for the mistakes, English is not my native language (this text is google translation)

Hello I am new to django and I have a question.
I have a table in DB with fields and boolean value "checked". You need to give access to check records to other users, and I would not want to give access to the admin panel.
How can I show a checkbox in a view along with a queryset in the table to set the value to true in the table and update only the rows selected by this checkbox? It needs to work as "Action" in the django admin panel

P.S. I tried through the form but it only creates a new record

p.p.s Now it turns out only to update ALL records of the table

**Here is my model.py**

```
class moIn(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='')
    dateUpdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ts = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='')
    pl = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='')
    rem = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='')
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name='', blank=True)
    staffer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='')
    checked = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='', default=False)
    checkedUser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='', blank=True, null=True, related_name='checkedUser')


    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.date)
        # return self.user

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
        verbose_name = ''
        verbose_name_plural = ''
```

You need to change the "checked" parameter through the template and automatically insert the user who sent the request into the "checkedUser"

P.p.p.s Additionally, I use the Django filter app for filtering

**views.py**

```
@login_required
# @user_passes_test(is_member_group)
def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.groups.filter(name='DashBoardAccess').exists():
        form = checkForm
        f = tableDashFilter(request.GET, queryset=moIn.objects.all())
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = checkForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = form.cleaned_data
                f.queryset.checked = data['checked']
                f.queryset.update(**data)
                return HttpResponse('ok')
        else:
            context = {
                'filter': f,
                'form': form
            }
            return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context)
    else:
        raise Http404()
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
                {%csrf_token%}
                <tbody class="table-view__body">
                    {% for out in filter.qs %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{form.checked}}</td>
                        <td>{{out.date|date:"d.m.Y"}}</td>
                        <td>{{out.ts}}</td>
                        <td>{{out.pl}}</td>
                        <td>{{out.rem}}</td>
                        <td>{{out.comment}}</td>
                        <td>{{out.checked}}</td>
                        <td>{{out.staffer}}</td>
                        <td>{{out.checkedUser}}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="submit">test</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: `f.qs.update(**data)`

Comment: When I select a check even in 1 record and press "submit", the value of all table elements is updated

Comment: You need to correctly filter the queryset to which `.update()` is applied. This is:
`f.queryset.update(**data)` the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69472453/how-can-i-filter-queryset-by-checked-form-checkboxes-in-django