# how can i filter queryset by checked form checkboxes in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I need to update the model according to the marked checkboxes in the django shape
How can I get only some of the table fields in a query

the "checked" line should be updated through the queryset
**models.py**

```
class moIn(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='')
    dateUpdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ts = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='')
    pl = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='')
    rem = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='')
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name='', blank=True)
    staffer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='')
    checked = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='', default=False)
    checkedUser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='', blank=True, null=True, related_name='checkedUser')
```

by clicking this checkbox, you will need to receive database records
***forms.py***

```
class checkForm(ModelForm):
    checked = fields.BooleanField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = moIn
        fields = {"id", "checked"}
```

***views.py***

```
def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.groups.filter(name='DashBoardAccess').exists():
        form = checkForm
        f = tableDashFilter(request.GET, queryset=moIn.objects.all())
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = checkForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                tt = form.save(commit=False)
                data = form.cleaned_data
                field = data['checked']=True
                f.qs.filter(checked=field).update(checked=True, checkedUser=request.user)
                return HttpResponse('ok')
        else:
            context = {
                'filter': f,
                'form': form
            }
            return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context)
    else:
        raise Http404()
```

in a line in bold, you need to get only those lines in which the checkbox is marked

> ***f.qs.filter(checked=field).update(checked=True, checkedUser=request.user)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the fields using ".values ()" for the queryset, and to use it with foreignKey, you need to explicitly specify the model fields:

```
f = tableDashFilter(request.GET, queryset=moIn.objects.values('id','date','ts','pl','rem','comment','checked','staffer__username','checkedUser__username'))
```

"Value" from the input, it is also going to be obtained through:
Since there can be several values (marked checkboxes), there will be a ".getlist"

```
checkID = request.POST.getlist('checked')
```

**querySet filter:**

```
f.qs.filter(id__in=checkID).update(checked=True, checkedUser=request.user)
```

in the html template through the loop, iterate over and insert into the input value of the model id